# tooltipText bug causes JMenuItem to lose focus

Tags: java, macos, swing, tooltip, jmenuitem

I am working on a Java Swing GUI and am having a minor issue with tool tip text on popup menu items.

Basically when you hover over a *JMenuItem* it is supposed to leave that *JMenuItem* selected and display the desired tool tip text.

What actually happens is when the tool tip text is made visible a *StateChange* event seems to cause the relevant *JMenuItem* to lose selection status and so the tool tip text very quickly disappears. Note that this only happens the first time, if you move your mouse around you can get the *JMenuItem* to select again and it will also display the tool tip text properly. I could leave this but I was hoping to set a delay through the ToolTipManager's sharedInstance() which at this point would hurt the user-friendly side of things since the user would have to wait twice as long after realizing the issue themselves.

I built a very simple demo that reflects the problem I am seeing, am I missing something or is this just a Java 8 with Mac issue?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TestFrame {

    static JFrame jf = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args){
      jf = new JFrame();

      JPanel jp = new JPanel();
      jp.setBackground(Color.white);
      jp.setForeground(Color.black);

      JPopupMenu p = new JPopupMenu();

      JMenuItem jmi = new JMenuItem("An option");
      jmi.setToolTipText("mouse over text");
      jmi.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            System.out.println("CHANGED by: "+e.getSource().toString());
        }});

      p.add(jmi);

      jp.setComponentPopupMenu(p);

      jf.add(jp);
      jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      jf.setSize(1000, 500);
      jf.setPreferredSize(jf.getSize());
      jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I tried this modified version that runs on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). It's *seems* improved, but it still fails intermittently. It looks like a regression.

Console:

```
$ javac TestFrame.java ; java TestFrame
1.8.0_31
10.9.5
…
```

Code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28160300/230513 */
public class TestFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.version"));
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame jf = new JFrame();
            JPanel jp = new JPanel();
            JPopupMenu p = new JPopupMenu();
            JMenuItem jmi = new JMenuItem("An option");
            jmi.setToolTipText("Mouse over text");
            jmi.addChangeListener((ChangeEvent e) -> {
                System.out.println("Changed by: " + e.getSource().toString());
            });
            p.add(jmi);
            jp.setComponentPopupMenu(p);
            jf.add(jp);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            jf.pack();
            jf.setSize(320, 240);
            jf.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah that gives the exact same results on my machine. Guess its time to submit a bug report?

Comment: @trashgod [I found an interesting example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/645179/GUI/java/fireTableDataChanged-working)